# Why doesn't my onclick event handler in Javascript work?

Tags: php, javascript, window.open

I currently have a button when clicked it should open up a new window but I am getting this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`. I am using `window.open()`

```
$url = "http://www.google.com";
$button .= 
'<input type="button" value="Print Timetable" class="printButton" onclick="window.open('.$url.');"/>';
```

I have noticed that when I use window.open() with no parameters it works but when I pass in the `$url` variable all hell breaks loose. I get syntax errors. I've tried http://www.google.com, www.google.com and google.com to no avail!

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: post the HTML which you get in browser

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are missing the single quotes needed to encapsulate the url string.

```
$url = "http://www.google.com";
$button .= 
'<input type="button" value="Print Timetable" class="printButton" onclick="window.open(\''.$url.'\');"/>';
```

You're adding a layer of string encapsulation. When you pass a string value to a function  it must be in quotes, as it is a string.

```
doSomething('http://www.ibm.com/');
```

When you are doing this inline in your html, you need to encapsulate the javascript in double quotes so it becomes

```
onclick="doSomething('http://www.ibm.com/');";
```

Then, if you want PHP to echo that, or to assign it as variable, you need to enclose all of that in quotes, so you can do

```
<?php 
    //encapsulate in double quotes and escape double quotes
    echo " onclick=\"doSomething('http://www.ibm.com/');\" "; 

    //encapsulate in single quotes and escape single quotes
    echo ' onclick="doSomething(\'http://www.ibm.com/\'); '; 
 ?>
```

Any way you break it down you need have 3 string encapsulations embedded in one another, so you must find a way to differentiate between the quotes used in JS and the quotes used in PHP.

Otherwise you would have a problem.

```
<?php 

    //Houston We have a problem!
    echo " onclick="doSomething('http://www.ibm.com/');\" "; 
         ^         ^                                    ^ ^
 Open Quote       Close Quote                  Open Quote Close Quote 
 ?>
```

Comment: Thanks this worked :) Just spent 2 hours on this. Syntax errors always get me in web development. Damn it!

But I don't understand why I have to escape it. I assume because it is Javascript? Because when I am writing HTML in my PHP files don't have to escape anything e.g. $content = 'div class="'.$classname.'">

Comment: @JohnathanAu - because you are passing a `string` to the `window.open` function. Initially, you were trying to do was `window.open(http://google.com)`, which was wrong without the quotes.

Comment: See my updated response above. Summary, if you want to echo a quote in php you need to escape it. `echo "\""; ` yields `"` ... and `echo '\'';` yields `'`. The URL you're passing is a string so it needs quotes on the JS level.

Comment: Cheers mate, that was fantastic.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things wrong here:

You have a period character before the equals, eg

```
$button .=
```

Should be

```
$button =
```

And you need to escape your single quotes:

```
$url = "http://www.google.com";
$button = '<input type="button" value="Print Timetable" class="printButton" onclick="window.open(''.$url.'');"/>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it suppose to be like this:

```
$url = "http://www.google.com";
$button .= 
'<input type="button" value="Print Timetable" class="printButton" onclick="window.open("'.$url.'");"/>';
```

window.open() require quote or double quote

Comment: This also will not working since double quotes are being used to encapsulate the function text - you can't use them for function arguments too.